# How to export a public key in OpenSSL/libcrypto?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I've created an RSA key using:

```
RSA_generate_key(2048, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);
```

Now I want to export the public key to another party B. Right now, I've just memcpy'd the entire RSA* struct and sent that over the wire, and B is able to use that to encrypt using RSA_public_encrypt().

But I think in this case I've actually exported the entire public/private key pair, and not just the public key. I want to only export the public component of the RSA key. How do I use OpenSSL APIs to do that?

Thanks

Comment: actually, looks like just memcpy'ing the RSA* struct doesn't work when sending across the network. I even tried calling RSAPublicKey_dup() and then sending the RSA* returned by that over to B. But in either case, when B tries to encrypt using this public key, it gives me an access violation (presumably because the BIGNUM* pointers contained in the RSA* struct all point to invalid locations in memory on B).

So just to summarize my question: How do I do a simple export of an RSA public key to another party, so that I can start doing fun stuff like key exchange?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want the functions [`d2i_RSAPublicKey` and `i2d_RSAPublicKey`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/d2i_RSAPublicKey.html). i2d serializes a RSA key struct to a bytestring, and d2i does the reverse operation.